# I am trying to update multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

**This is the question:**

-If the price of the phone is less than R8000, then there is a price increase of R100
-If the price of the phone is R8000 or more, then there is a price reduction/decrease of 10% on the original selling price of the phone.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
UPDATE       tblPhoneDetails
SET          CellPhone_UnitPrice = CellPhone_UnitPrice - 100
WHERE        (CellPhone_UnitPrice < '8000'),
SET          CellPhone_UnitPrice = CellPhone_UnitPrice - CellPhone_UnitPrice * 0.1
WHERE        (CellPhone_UnitPrice > '8000')
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag only the one database that you are running.

Comment: @KaylaThompson . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  In addition, you are setting `CellPhone_UnitPrice` to a number value but you are comparing it as a string.  What is the real type?  What comparisons do you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
update tblphonedetails
set cellphone_unitprice = case 
    when cellphone_unitprice < 8000 then cellphone_unitprice - 100 
    else cellphone_unitprice * 0.9
end
```